# Controlling html outside the ngview when page changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page angular application and this is my index.html file:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
<div id="bash">...</div>
...
<div id="menu">...</div>
...
<div ng-view></div>
...
</html>
```

Then I have a home controller with its template and an about us controller with its own template as well. And I want their templates to come up in the ng-view which is happening already but I want the `#bash` to only come up when the url ends with `/home` and hide when the url ends with anything else.

I can't do that through the home controller because it's outside the ng-view

and I can't do this through a normal JS file as well because the application loads once.

I can go through each controller and have a js function that changes `#bash`'s css and turns display into false but I'd rather just have a condition in one place and I'm sure it's doable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why couldn't you do that from the home controller?

```
<div id="bash" ng-show="bashShown()">...</div>

...

$scope.bashShown = function() {
    return $location.path().endsWith('/home');
};
```

Comment: It doesn't get called because it's outside the home controller's scope as it's outside the ng-view

Comment: Put that in your main controller, the one controlling the bash div. If you don't have such a controller... create it: `<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">`.